# Improvement for rebuilded table design

Tags: tables, fontsize, threeparttable

I want to rebuild the following table : [image: Table to rebuild]

and came up with the following code :

```
\begin{table}
\centering
  \begin{threeparttable}
       \caption{ \\ \textit{Quantile Effects When Education is Treated as Exogenous} \\
    \scriptsize (Sample size : 7,165) By gender (3,735 males and 3,430 females)}
     \begin{tabular}{llllll}
        \toprule
         & \( \tau=0.10 \) & \( \tau= 0.30 \) & \( \tau= 0.50 \) & \( \tau= 0.70 \) & \( \tau= 0.90 \) \\
        \midrule     \\
        \textit{Males}    & $\underset{( 0.2359)}{-0.0852}$        & $\underset{(0.1127)}{0.0657}$    & $\underset{(0.1045)}{-0.1358}$       & $\underset{(0.1231)}{-0.0983}$ & $\underset{(0.1989)}{-0.2911}$    \\
        \textit{Females}& $\underset{( 0.2090}{0.3149}$        & $\underset{(0.1034)}{0.0815}$    & $\underset{(0.097)}{-0.1358}$       & $\underset{(0.1035)}{0.1224}$ & $\underset{(0.2221)}{  0.0947}$ \\
        \bottomrule
     \end{tabular}
    \begin{tablenotes}
      \small
      \item \textit{Note.} Each regression included a constant, country dummies,  \textit{q}, \textit{$q^2$} and their interactions with country dummies, age, age squared, and the GDP per head at the age when the pupil would have finished compulsory schooling. $\tau$  denotes the quantile of the distribution of wages. Three start, two stas and one star for statistically significant coefficients at the 1\%, 5\% and 10\% confidence level. Bootstrapped standard errors are shown in parentheses. 
    \end{tablenotes}
  \end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
```

Which looks like this : [image: Result so far.]

Specific improvement questions :

How can I center 'Table 5' and my caption in my result?

Is there any way to set the font-size of a threeparttable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution for the caption, with the homonymous package. I also improved a bit the table note. For the font size, this depends on which part you want to change it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{booktabs, array, caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering\captionsetup{labelsep=newline, justification=centering}
  \begin{threeparttable}
       \caption{\textit{Quantile Effects When Education is Treated as Exogenous} \\
    \scriptsize (Sample size : 7,165) By gender (3,735 males and 3,430 females)}
     \begin{tabular}{*{6}{l}}
        \toprule
         & \( \tau=0.10 \) & \( \tau= 0.30 \) & \( \tau= 0.50 \) & \( \tau= 0.70 \) & \( \tau= 0.90 \) \\
        \midrule
        \addlinespace
        \textit{Males} & $\underset{( 0.2359)}{-0.0852}$ & $\underset{(0.1127)}{0.0657}$ & $\underset{(0.1045)}{-0.1358}$ & $\underset{(0.1231)}{-0.0983}$ & $\underset{(0.1989)}{-0.2911}$ \\
        \textit{Females}& $\phantom{-}\underset{( 0.2090)}{0.3149}$ & $\underset{(0.1034)}{0.0815}$ & $\underset{(0.097)}{-0.1358}$ & $\phantom{-}\underset{(0.1035)}{0.1224}$ & $\phantom{-}\underset{(0.2221)}{ 0.0947}$ \\
        \bottomrule
     \end{tabular}
    \begin{tablenotes}[flushleft]
      \small
      \item \textit{Note.} Each regression included a constant, country dummies, \textit{q}, \textit{$q^2$} and their interactions with country dummies, age, age squared, and the GDP per head at the age when the pupil would have finished compulsory schooling. $\tau$ denotes the quantile of the distribution of wages. Three start, two stas and one star for statistically significant coefficients at the 1\%, 5\% and 10\% confidence level. Bootstrapped standard errors are shown in parentheses.
    \end{tablenotes}
  \end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hmm strange to say but my LaTex-Compiler (Knitr in R Markdown) throws me the following error : `! Package caption Error: \caption outside float.

See the caption package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.642 \caption
              { \\ \textit{Quantile Effects When Education is Treated as Exo.. `

Comment: The error message shows it is not the exact code I used: I  deleted the initial \\ in the caption text since I set `labelsep=newline`. In the posted code, \caption is inside the `threeparttable` environment.  Please check the code you use.

Comment: It is the exact code you used. See : 
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gXeGp.png

But I think knitR is doing something terrible there wenn compiling the code D:

Comment: Of course, I  compiled with a basic pdflatex, and I don't know what knitR does, but I'm surprised, as it uses only standard packages.

Comment: Yeah it is really strange, of course the code works for me perfectly fine when I use basic pdflatex or XeLatex, too. But I think I can find a workaround, say just compile the R-Code first and leave me with the plain Latex Code. The latter can be pushed into any standard Tex-Compiler and I will remove the erroneous backlashes.

Comment: Just an idea: if you don't need the environment to float, remove  the `table` environment, and put `\centering\captionsetup{…}` just after `\begin{threeparttable}`, and  see what happens.

Comment: ... fixed it. The floating caption error was in another table. I just had to check the line of the error and would have blamed myself, instead of the machine. Thanks for the help anyway.

Comment: All's well that ends well! :-)

Answer (score 3):

Here's another possible solution. Observe that it aligns the decimal markers within each column. Since you seem to be keen on using a `threepartable` environment, I also suggest using `\tnote` directives. I don't think that the sample size information deserves to be all that close to the caption.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{input-symbols= (),
         group-digits=false,
         table-space-text-post = )}
         
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\renewcommand\TPTtagStyle{\textit}

\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{labelsep=newline,
              textfont=it,
              skip=0.333\baselineskip}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{Quantile effects when education is treated as exogenous\tnote{a,b}}

\begin{tabular}{@{} l *{5}{S[table-format=-1.4]} @{}}
\toprule
& \multicolumn{5}{c@{}}{$\tau$}\\
\cmidrule(l){2-6}
& 0.10 & 0.30 & 0.50 & 0.70 & 0.90 \\
\midrule    
Males    & -0.0852 & 0.0657 & -0.1358 & -0.0983 & -0.2911 \\
  & (0.2359) & (0.1127) & (0.1045) & (0.1231) & (0.1989) \\
\addlinespace
Females  &  0.3149 & 0.0815 & -0.1358 & 0.1224 & 0.0947 \\
  & (0.2090) & (0.1034) & (0.097)  & (0.1035) & (0.2221) \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
     
\smallskip\small
\begin{tablenotes}
\item[a]Sample size: 7,165. By gender: 3,735 males and 3,430 females.
\item[b]Each regression included a constant, country dummies,  \textit{q}, \textit{$q^2$} and their interactions with country dummies, age, age squared, and the GDP per head at the age when the pupil would have finished compulsory schooling. $\tau$  denotes the quantile of the distribution of wages. Three stars, two stars and one star denote statistically significant coefficients at the 1\%, 5\% and 10\% confidence levels. Bootstrapped standard errors are shown in parentheses. 
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end {document}
```